# How to reuse an iterator in different functions?

Tags: iteration, iterators

How can I reuse iterators?
For example, instead of

```
Table[i, {i,0,10}]
Table[i^2, {i,0,10}]
Table[f[i], {i,0,10}]
```

write something like

```
iter={i,0,10}
Table[i, iter]
Table[i^2, iter]
Sum[f[i], iter]
```

Comment: Maybe: `Unevaluated@Table[i, iter] /. OwnValues[iter]`

Comment: Your `iter` is just `Range[0, 10]`, then `Range[0, 10]`, `Range[0,10]^2`, `Total[f/@Range[0,10]]`

Answer (score 6):

```
iter = {i, 0, 10};
```

Since `Table` "holds" all its arguments you must `Evaluate` iter

```
Table[i^2, Evaluate @ iter]
```

{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}

```
Attributes[Table]
```

{HoldAll, Protected}

A simple example from the documentation of `Evaluate`

```
Hold[Evaluate[1 + 1], 2 + 2]
```

Hold[2, 2 + 2]

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, and maybe pedantic, but nevertheless...

You probably don't want to do that at all (although the `Evaluate` suggestions work fine if this is a "quick and dirty" situation). It is certainly valuable to be able to repeat a particular iteration pattern across several different expressions, but this isn't the way to do it if you want long term maintainability and ease of variation. The reason is because your iterator specification cannot be specified independently from the expression you're iterating over. And that's because you must include the iteration variable `i` in the iterator pattern, and of course that variable is now expected to show up in the "prototype" in the `Table`.

**Alternate #1**

Encapsulate just the parameters of the iteration pattern:

```
{start, stop, step} = {0, 10, 1};
Table[i^2, {i, start, stop, step}]
```

Now start, stop, and step can be shared.

**Alternate #2**

Use anonymous functions and the built-in symbols that are designed to work with them:

```
count = 11;
endpoints = {0, 10};
Array[#^2 &, count, endpoints]
```

Now count and endpoints can be shared, and even derived from start, stop, and step if you need to share across different iteration styles.

**Alternate #3**

Use a function-composition style rather than an iterative one.

```
range = Range[0, 10];
Total[range^2]
```

Now range can be shared, even in your `Table` if you really want that:

```
Table[i^2, {i, range}]
```

And so forth...

There are many ways other ways to precisely encapsulate and share stuff, but the main point is to not strongly couple things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1

```
i = 13: (* check evaluation leakage *)
ClearAll[iter];
SetAttributes[iter, HoldAll];
iter[cmd_[f_]] := cmd[f, {i, 0, 10}];
iter@Table[i]
iter@Table[i^2]
Sum[f[i]] // iter
```

Version 2

```
i = 13: (* check evaluation leakage *)
ClearAll[iter];
myiter = 
  Function[expr, 
   Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[iter] :> {i, 0, 10} // ReleaseHold, 
   HoldAll];
Table[i, iter] // myiter
Table[i^2, iter] // myiter
Sum[f[i], iter] // myiter
Table[i + 10 j, {j, 2}, iter] // myiter
Table[i + 10 j, iter, {j, 2}] // myiter
```

Version 3

```
i = 13: (* check evaluation leakage *)
ClearAll[iter];
iter /: cmd_[x__, iter, y___] := cmd[x, {i, 0, 10}, y];
Table[i, iter]
Table[i^2, iter]
Sum[f[i], iter]
Table[i + 10 j, {j, 2}, iter]
Table[i + 10 j, iter, {j, 2}]
```